# Using JavaFx animation to move a player

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating a game in JavaFx where a player moves up and down (player moves down automatically to simulate gravity) and dodges incoming obstacles. For the player, I was just going to import a picture and use imageview as the player. Is there anyway to simulate the movement in javaFx with timeline animation or transition and have a collision detection system with the obstacles? As far as I know, there is no way to get coordinates of a node that is already in animation so I have no way of knowing if the player touched the obstacles or not. Sorry if this is a long read.

Comment: I would not use `Timeline`s or `Transition`s for this kind of animation. There's a pretty nice introduction to game programming in JavaFX in Steven van Impe's blog. The [first part](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) talks about some general issues with game loops and timing, and the [second part](http://asipofjava.blogspot.com/2014/05/game-loops-and-applying-them-to-javafx.html?m=0) shows how to implement those ideas using an [`AnimationTimer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).